# How to connect to django channel socket?

Tags: websocket, django-channels

I followed the [tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html) on the official site of the django channels. Everything is fine. But now, how do I connect to the ongoing socket and push message to the group in the server side (i.e. via django) ?

In the tutorial, following line of code in the js opens up a WebSocket connection simply by calling the WebSocket constructor:

```
var chatSocket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');
```

And I want to connect to the same socket in the server side. I tried this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('ws://127.0.0.1/ws/chat/2', 6379))
```

but I get error saying

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I am a complete beginner in socket programming, and apologize if there is anything minor that I may have skipped.

Comment: Can you show me your consumers and routing.py file ?

Comment: @Raja The files are here, https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_3.html

Comment: I just want to know where did you get these line  `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` ?

Comment: that line is just what I tried, in order to connect to the socket connection opened by the django channels.